# PSQL/Knex Insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

Using knex in a node/express server to migrate and seed my postgreSQL database. The migrations go through and in SQLite3 it has no problem seeding the data, but when I convert it to a postgreSQL database I get this FK constraint error on the user id. I've generated the seed data programmatically and manually in a json file and the same error persists.

`Error: Error while executing "/Users/andre/projects/React-native/Lambda-Social-App/server/data/seeds/002-Subtopics.js" seed: insert into "subtopic" ("creater_id", "title") values ($1, $2), ($3, $4), ($5, $6), ($7, $8), ($9, $10), ($11, $12), ($13, $14), ($15, $16), ($17, $18), ($19, $20), ($21, $22), ($23, $24), ($25, $26), ($27, $28), ($29, $30), ($31, $32), ($33, $34), ($35, $36), ($37, $38), ($39, $40) - insert or update on table "subtopic" violates foreign key constraint "subtopic_creater_id_foreign"
    at _bluebird.default.resolve.then.then.catch.originalError (/Users/andre/projects/React-native/Lambda-Social-App/node_modules/knex/lib/seed/Seeder.js:137:21)
error: insert or update on table "subtopic" violates foreign key constraint "subtopic_creater_id_foreign"`

User.js

```
    exports.up = function (knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('users', user => {

    user.string('id').unique().primary().notNullable();
    user.string('username', 25).notNullable();
    user.string('email', 128).unique().notNullable();
    user.string('avatar', 100).notNullable();
    user.timestamps(true, true);
  });
};
```

Subtopic.js

```
exports.up = function (knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('subtopic', subtopic => {

    subtopic.increments('id').primary().notNullable();
    subtopic.string('title', 50).unique().notNullable();
    subtopic.timestamp(true, true);
    subtopic.string('creator_id').notNullable().references('id').inTable('users').onDelete('CASCADE').onUpdate('CASCADE');
  });
};
```

Comment: FK constraint violation error is a data error. You have a row in the child table that does not exist in the parent.  No variation of sending it will work until you correct the data.Are you sure your version of SQLite enforces FK constraints. Up to version 3.6.xx it could not (but that is old you are probably ok) but even then it requires special compile options before FK constraints are enforced. IMO this shows the facially of not developing on the target databse.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'm using SQLite3 v:4.0.8 for development, never really had a problem switching a basic db to pg for production though I agree this would have probably been easier to debug had I developed in the target db. Lesson learned.. I've manually added the data myself so I know that the rows exist so I'm not sure where it would find the issue since I'm simply referencing the PK on the users table as a FK for the subtopic table.

Comment: Can you post the table DDL. From the latest description "referencing the PK on the users table as a FK for the subtopic" and the error description "subtopic" violates foreign key constraint "subtopic_creater_id_foreign" it looks like the FK is defined backwards.

Comment: so I decided to manually insert the data in pgadmin and you were right. For some reason some of the user data was making it through everything except the user table. Thanks for your help @Belayer

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.